# Artifacts without ngons

Tags: faces, artifacts

Blender community. I am modeling the cockpit windows of an airplane with a new (for me) method. Earlier, I did that with the Knife projection tool. But after it, I was getting a lot of artifacts because of ngons. Now, I make a window shape, and then manually connect it to the fuselage. I try to avoid ngons but it's not always possible. In the artifact area, I have no ngons. Cannot understand why. Help is very appriciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: well you have 4 gons that is true, but mesh like this is technically still a lot messy and some of the vertices are higher and some are lower, some are too close to each other, some are too far away, some 4 gons have 1 intercepting vertices... You still need to somehow smooth this are... I am not sure but maybe you can try to use sculpt and smooth brush with very low strength about 0.05 and try to smooth it

Comment: you should work with less polygons, you don't really have artefacts per se, it's just that your topology tends to flatten some parts, and it will be hard to rework as your topology is too dense for the moment, and not very good (it doesn't follow the shape enough)

Comment: Good topology isn't just about avoiding n-gons (which itself isn't a valid principle). It's more importantly about edge flow. Each edge or vertice you add that goes agains the flow of your shape will create pinches, distortions and whatnot. I.E. look at [this topic](https://blenderartists.org/t/aircraft-modeling-cockpit-windows-issue/1229465/24). See the evolution until Freezerinos's post at the end. Also, don't make things harder for yourself, if your model is made of different parts in real life, you can make them in different mesh parts as well.

Comment: Good topology isn't just about avoiding n-gons (which itself isn't a valid principle). It's more importantly about edge flow. Each edge or vertice you add that goes agains the flow of your shape will create pinches, distortions and whatnot. I.E. look at this topic. See the evolution until Freezerinos's post at the end. Also, don't make things harder for yourself, if your model is made of different parts in real life, you can make them in different mesh parts as well. – L0Lock *Thank you L0Lock. This worked for me. In my opinion, now my mesh looks better.*
[![enter image description here](https